# Compute $ \int \frac {x^2}{(x^2 - x + 1)^{1/2}} dx $

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I search on math.stack but couldn't find a method to compute this integral

$$ \int \frac {x^2}{(x^2 - x + 1)^{1/2}} dx$$

meaning a function $$ f(x) = \frac {P(x)}{(Q(x))^{1/2}} $$

where P and Q are polynoms of degre 2

I succesfully simplified my expression writing it like this :

$$  \int (x^2 - x + 1)^{1/2} dx +  1/2 * \int \frac {2x - 1}{(x^2 - x + 1)^{1/2}} dx - 1/2  \int \frac {1}{(x^2 - x + 1)^{1/2}}dx $$

but apart from the integral from the center, I can't compute it either.

Thank you for your help

Comment: $$x^2-x+1=\dfrac{(2x-1)^2+3}4$$  Set $2x-1=\sqrt3\tan t$

Comment: yes I also found this but I don't really like using the trigonometric functions when they don't appear at the beginning and here, you don't have already the form of arctan. 

After the simplification for the third integral, I agree, you could use this method, but from the start it is to obvious

Comment: Take a look at the Related sidebar, does it show something similar? Maybe this?  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2422402/finding-int-fracx-sqrt3-2x-x2-dx?rq=1  Also note that at that link in Related there are also some similar examples.

Comment: If you don't like some answers, you should better say so in the question: "without using trigonometric functions", in this case. You're right, too, $2x-1=\sqrt3\sinh t$ would make more sense.

Comment: @MarineGalantin Using trigonometric substitution is the standard method for handling integrals of this type, and in some cases it is unavoidable, in the sense that antiderivatives of algebraic (and even rational functions) sometimes involve inverse trigonometric functions; consider $\int \frac{dx}{1 + x^2} = \arctan x + C$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitute $$\sqrt{x^2-x+1}=t+x$$ then we get
$$x=\frac{1-t^2}{2t+1}$$
and
$$dx=-2\,{\frac {{t}^{2}+t+1}{ \left( 2\,t+1 \right) ^{2}}}dt$$
after this substiution we hae
$$\int \frac{\left(\frac{1-t^2}{2t+1}\right)^2}{\frac{t^2+t+1}{2t+1}}\cdot \frac{t^2+t+1}{2t+1}dt$$
which can simplified to $$\int {\frac { \left( -{t}^{2}+1 \right) ^{2}}{ \left( 2\,t+1 \right) ^{2}}}dt$$

Comment: how did you think about something like this ? 
Doesn't it make the expression more awfull?

Comment: it is a Standard Substitution, and we get a rational Expression in $t$ which can be easy to integrate, i will send you a link

Comment: see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution

Comment: oh I see. When they write $R(x, f(x) )$, can you confirm that it is the expression of a rationnal function with the form $ f(x)$ used either up or down ? E.G. here they say $$f(x) = sqrt(ax^2 + bx + c)$$ so you can use it either for $$ f(x) = \frac {1}{(Q(x))^{1/2}} $$ or $$ f(x) = (Q(x))^{1/2} $$

Comment: one Moment i will, this compute for you!

Comment: this should simplified

Comment: thank you :) really helpfull. That's what i searched

Comment: use this here $$\frac{(1-t^2)^2}{(2t+1)^2}=1/4\,{t}^{2}-t/4-{\frac{5}{16}}+3/4\, \left( 2\,t+1 \right) ^{-1}+{
\frac {9}{16\, \left( 2\,t+1 \right) ^{2}}}
$$